# Visual Studio Team Services Set Build Number From On-Premises Build Agent

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an on-premises build agent running on Azure to create builds of a Unity 3D app. The builds work great but I'd like a way to push the build name back to Visual Studio Team Services so it populates the **Implementation** dropdown in tickets:

[image]

I've found I can [set variables in VSTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190719.aspx) but part of my build name comes from Unity itself so there's no way for VSTS to know what the build name will be. I'd like the build names in VSTS to match the actual builds that Unity produces if at all possible.

Is it possible to push build names into VSTS from a build agent such that the **Implementation** dropdown is populated?

This is what my build list looks like after trying Pascal Berger's suggestion:

[image]

Comment: Are you using XAML builds or the new web based builds?

Comment: @PascalBerger I believe I'm using the new web based builds. I followed the steps starting with "Configuring the Build Agent" on [this page](http://techtwaddle.net/2015/07/07/setting-up-an-on-premise-build-agent-with-visual-studio-online/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the new web based build system you can use the [##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]build number logging command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) for example in a PowerShell Script to set the build number like this, where `UnityBuildNumber` should be set to the build number as defined by unity:

```
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]UnityBuildNumber"
```

On the build definition (under the general tab) you need to set the build number format to `$(build.buildNumber)` to use the build number as name of the build.

Comment: I installed the node package from your link and ran the command locally via Powershell on my Azure VM (where the build agent is installed) and I'm not seeing the build number show up in VSO. Am I missing a step? How should I confirm that VSO is receiving the build number?

Comment: Which node package? You shouldn't need to install a node package for this. These are the logging commands which are implemented in the build agent itself. Just add a new task to your build definition which calls a PowerShell script and add the `Write-Host` statement to it.

Comment: I've create the PS script and added a build step to my build definition and I'm still not seeing the build number in VSO. Is there a place in VSO where I can look at all the build numbers? I'm just looking at the Implementation field in a ticket.

Comment: Not sure if the implementation field is set using the web based build system. You can see the build number in the build hub if you click on the build definition (name column)

Comment: I'm not seeing the build number (I've added an image to my question so show what I'm looking at).

Comment: 73, 74 and 75 are the build numbers in your image. How does your `build.updatebuildnumber` call look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100913/discussion-between-noobsarepeople2-and-pascal-berger).

Comment: Updated answer with the findings from our chat discussion